# String manipulation in ItemStyle.xsl file for Content query web part

Tags: xslt, content-query-web-part, xslt-list-view-web-part

i have image tag in ItemStyle.xsl file with  my custom style template,

here i have set image **"src"** attribute

```
      <img height="220px;">  
        <xsl:attribute name="src">  
            <xsl:value-of select="@ProfilePicture" />  
        </xsl:attribute>  
      </img>
```

but my custom column with name **ProfilePicture**  type Hyperlink sets values **"http://pc1/Profile%20Pictures/Abc.jpg, joe"**

here m trying to get **"http://pc1/Profile%20Pictures/Abc.jpg"** url by using string manipulation .

my current images tag display like below:-

```
    <img src="http://pc1/Profile%20Pictures/Abc.jpg, joe"/>
```

m trying to display like this

```
    <img src="http://pc1/Profile%20Pictures/Abc.jpg"/>
```

Comment: search for ``XSLT and substring-before``

Comment: @Danny Engelman , thanx found this:-                                                                                                                           
substring-before('aa-bb','-')    output:- aa